# Rotation handles won't pop up on mask

Tags: video, masking

I have a mask I'm animating around an object and, when you first draw the mask, if you drag at all when you drop a point, a rotation handle will pop up (see pic below for reference). Well, I have a lot of other points that don't have the rotation handle on them because I didn't drag when I drew that point. **How do I bring up this rotation handle on the mask points that don't have them originally?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. What you do, is you go over to your toolbar, and you hit "set handle type" then you can go down to the menu that popped up as a result of hitting it and change the handle type to your liking.
The shortcut for this is "V".

[image]